# Extract mapped columns from SSIS package

Tags: ssis, mapping

I am using .NET to extract meta data from an SSIS package.

Is there a way to extract the mapping information from and OLEDB source (no variable used for statement) and it's destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although you'll have to get deep into the weeds of the [IDTSPipeline100](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.mainpipe%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and associated interfaces to do so:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;

namespace CSharpConsoleApp
{
    class PackageDemo
    {
        public void CountColumns(string packagePath, string dataFlowName)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            Package package = app.LoadPackage(packagePath, null);

            TaskHost th = package.Executables[dataFlowName] as TaskHost;
            MainPipe mp = th.InnerObject as MainPipe;
            foreach (IDTSComponentMetaData100 md in mp.ComponentMetaDataCollection)
            {
                foreach (IDTSOutput100 output in md.OutputCollection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Component {0} output {1} has {2} columns", 
                        md.Name, output.Name, output.OutputColumnCollection.Count);
                    foreach (IDTSOutputColumn100 column in output.OutputColumnCollection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\tcolumn {0} ({1}) is of type {2}", 
                            column.ID, column.Name, column.DataType);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you will need references to the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsPipelineWrap` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsRuntimeWrap` DLLs for this code to compile.

Comment: Hi Edmund, does this apply to data flows within a sequence container? When I pass the name of the dataflow task in a sequence container, I beleive the only executable in package is the container itself.

Comment: Yes, although in that case you'd need two steps. First, get the Sequence from the package's `Executables` collection. Next, get the DataFlow from the `Executables` collection of the Sequence object.

Comment: There`s a little more to it than getting the DataFlow from the Executables collection. http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Searching-for-tasks.aspx